# SOAP UI - Set a node value in all test step's requests of all test cases in a test suites

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to set a node value in all test step's requests xml of all test cases in a test suite.

The groovy script is in the first test case and I get an error (XmlException: Unexpected Element: CDATA) as soon as the script try to edit the same tag in the second test case.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def AlltestCases = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites[testRunner.testCase.testSuite.name] 

0.upto(AlltestCases.getTestCaseCount()) {
     AlltestCases.getTestCaseList().each{ 
     it.getTestStepList().each{ if(it.getClass()==com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep){ 
     if(it.getName().toLowerCase().contains("verify")){ 

     step = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("${it.getName()}"+"#Request") 
     step.setNodeValue("//*:Name/text()", "\$"+"{#TestSuite#NAME_ID}") 
     step.updateProperty() 

             } 
          } 
       } 
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to "inject" a value in a number of requests?

I would advise against that. I would rather set some project property, and then let each of the requests simply use that particular variable.

The most important reason for me to prefer this approach, is to make it more tranparent what is happening in your testcase, should someone else at some point - like if you get a different job - would need to take over your SoapUI projects. Currently you have requests, which hold values that appear to come out of nowhere. I would advise to make it clear that the request contains some sort of variable, and where that variable comes from.

Besides you will then also get more flexibility. If a few reqeusts at some point changes the path or name of the entity you want to change, you will need to make your code above handle that kind of situation. Not so, if you are merely using a variable in each of your requests.